# No stdout from this Rscript command in Powershell

Tags: r, powershell, rscript

I'm trying to write the equivalent of this Bash command in Windows:

```
(tee <<"EOF"
<some-markdown-and-html>
EOF
) | Rscript -e '
input <- file("stdin", "r")
content <- readLines(input)
print(content)
'
```

I am quite unfamiliar with Windows, and thought Powershell seemed like a good choice, however I have a strange issue outputting text to stdout.  This command works:

```
(@" 
<some-markdown-and-html>
"@) | Rscript -e @"
print(readLines(file('stdin', 'r')))
"@
```

has the desired output:

```
[1] "<some-markdown-and-html>"
```

however when I break the R script into multiple lines it outputs nothing:

```
(@" 
<some-markdown-and-html>
"@) | Rscript -e @"
input <- file('stdin', 'r')
content <- readLines(input)
print(content)
"@
```

How can I print to stdout with a multiline R script?  Doesn't need to be Powershell, just Windows compatible (ideally without installing WSL).  Thanks

Comment: Can you get a multiline RScript working without being part of the pipe, possibly changing  `stdin` to an example file?

Comment: Separate question: Does R allow stringing multiple statements on a single line, e.g., `do-line-1; do-line-2; do-line-3`?

Comment: The only obvious difference is that the string passed to `-e` in your Bash command starts with a newline and ends with one, whereas the PowerShell one does not; I'm not familiar with Rscript, but I wouldn't expect this difference to matter.